# How to enable varnish daemon in Cygwin?

Tags: varnish, cygwin

I've installed the varnish packages (3.0.2-1 or 2.1.5-1) in cygwin (for local testing of VCL on Win7 64bit) and want to start varnish listening on port 80 but the varnishd isn't available:

```
$ varnishd -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl -s malloc,1G -T 127.0.0.1:2000 -a 0.0.0.0:80
-bash: varnishd: Command not found.
```

so i've installed initscripts and sysvinit packages and reinstalled varnish but still varnishd isn't available!

What additonal packages are necessary to get this running?

Comment: Can you try to use full path? "/usr/sbin/varnishd"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion in comment to use full path to the binary "/usr/sbin/varnishd" helped OP with the issue.

Comment: I've also added PATH="/usr/sbin:${PATH}" to $HOME/.bash_profile - now it's directly accesible.

Comment: Yep, That'd do it. Good Job.